# KOMA-script align vertically align margin notes with section headings

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, marginpar

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\section{Foo bar}

\marginline{A note}

Foo bar baz.

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

how can I vertically align the margin note to have it at the same height of the section heading, without the blank space I get now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to put the `\marginline` command *inside* the argument to `\section`. Note, however, that this would also attempt to put a `\marginline` in the page header (and table of contents if you had it) which is likely not desired. Instead, you would have to use the optional argument to `\section` to create a version that doesn't do that:

```
\section[Foo bar]{Foo bar \marginline{A note}}
```